# Await reading document and then setup listener?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Using Flutter and Firestore I frequently setup this block of code.

```
DocumentReference reference = Firestore.instance.collection('movies').document(uid);
reference.snapshots().listen((documentSnapshot) {
  <respond to updates>
});
```

This fires the listen for the initial read and any changes.

However sometimes I want to do an await for the first read and then setup the listener for changes.  How can I do that?  Specifically how do I await for the first read, and second make the listen not fire unless there are any changes?